# Three.js: How to make a rounded rectangle with PlaneGeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've seen another question where the user merges four circle geometries and two plane geometries which works to a certain extent . Is there a simple way to give a PlaneGeometry rounded edges? In 3D software I would have to chamfer the edges and increase segments. Is there a way to replicate this process in Three.js? Basically my question is how to give a PlaneGeometry rounded corners in the simplest way. Thanks so much.

Comment: The code is written for you in [this three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html).